# Rails 4 - NoMethodError in BookingsController#create when using Nested Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating a ticket booking app for my sample project using Ruby on Rails 4.1. Three are three models - Events, Tickets and Bookings. Events have many tickets and bookings. Tickets have many bookings and they belong to events. Bookings belongs to events and tickets.

Here's how the nested route looks like:

```
resources :events do
  resources :tickets
  resources :bookings
end
```

The ticket controller works perfectly fine and here's the controller code:

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController
def index
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @tickets = @event.tickets.all
end

def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @ticket = @event.tickets.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @ticket = Ticket.new
end

def create
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @ticket = @event.tickets.create(ticket_params)
    if @ticket.save
        redirect_to [@event, @ticket]
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @ticket= @event.tickets.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @ticket = @event.tickets.find(params[:id])

    if @ticket.update(ticket_params)
        redirect_to [@event, @ticket]
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @ticket = @event.tickets.find(params[:id])
    @ticket.destroy
    redirect_to event_tickets_path
end


private

def ticket_params
    params.require(:ticket).permit(:ticket_name, :booking_start_date, :booking_end_date, :ticket_price, :ticket_quantity, :minimum_quantity, :maximum_quantity, :terms_conditions, :more_information)
end
```

end

However, when I follow the steps to create a bookings controller, I get an error message:

```
NoMethodError in BookingsController#create

undefined method `bookings' for #<Event:0x007f84dd6cc7a8>
```

The booking controller looks like this:

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
def new
 @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
 @booking = Booking.new
end

def create
  @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
  @booking = @event.bookings.create(booking_params)
  if @booking.save
    redirect_to [@event, @booking]
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def show
  @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
  @booking = @event.bookings.find(params[:id])
end

private

def booking_params
  params.require(:booking).permit(:buyer_name, :email, :mobile, :address, :order_quantity)
end
end
```

Can somebody let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you defined `has_many :bookings` in the `Event` model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you forgot to declare the relation between Event and Booking, on the Event side: make sure that you have the following `has_many`:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookings
  # etc.
```

Comment: Thanks you so much! I missed that one.